# How to activate conda virtual environment in linux using Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, conda

I am just trying to activate conda virtual environment using python in linux. I am using subprocess module. It works fine when I used conda activate in terminal but this doesn't seem to work in pyhton. My code is

```
subprocess.run('conda activate ENV_NAME',shell=True)
```

but when I execute this simple code, got the following error

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

    Currently supported shells are:
      - bash
      - fish
      - tcsh
      - xonsh
      - zsh
      - powershell
    
    See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.
    
    IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

Please help me what should i do? Tried all solutions from stackoverflow but still getting the same error. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do, why activate an environment that way?

Comment: I have attached some hardware and I just want to execute it in single command without having to first activate virtual environment through terminal

Comment: Well, fortunately, i found a way to do this using os.system.